# Construction of Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Given $10$ random variables $W_1,W_2,\cdots,W_{10}\stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim}N(\mu,\sigma)$, where $\mu,\sigma$ are **unknown**. How can we construct a **known** function $f$ such that $Y=f(W_1,W_2,\cdots,W_{10})\sim N(0,1)$?

> Note, here **known function** means there is no $\mu,\sigma$ in $f$, e.g. $f_1=\frac{X_1-\mu}{\sigma}$ is unknown and $f_2=3X_1-e^{X_2}+X_3$ is known.

Firstly I successfully make $\mu$ become $0$: I let $Y_1=W_1-W_2,Y_2=W_3-W_4,\cdots,Y_5=W_9-W_{10}$ then $Y_1,\cdots,Y_5\stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} N(0,2\sigma^2)$. However then I cannot eliminate $\sigma$. I tried use some f to approach $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ and I've tried many functions like
$Z=\frac{Y_3}{\sqrt{Y_1^2+Y_2^2}}$ and $Z=\frac{Y_1^2+Y_2^2}{\ln(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{Y_1}{Y_2}+\frac{1}{2})}$  but nothing worked. Can someone give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas! We bypass $\sigma$ and use $Y_1,\cdots,Y_4$ to generate two i.i.d angles $U_1,U_2\sim U(0,2\pi)$ then use them to get $U(0,1)$ and generate normal distribution!

specific proof:
Let
$$
Y_1=W_1-W_2,~Y_2=W_3-W_4,\cdots,Y_4=W_7-W_8
$$
Then $Y_1,\cdots,Y_4\stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim}N(0,2\sigma^2)$. Let
$$
U_1=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan\dfrac{Y_1}{Y_2}+\dfrac{1}{2},~U_2=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan\dfrac{Y_3}{Y_4}+\dfrac{1}{2}
$$
Then $U_1,U_2\stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim}U(0,1)$，Then
$$
Z=\sqrt{-2\ln U_1}\cos(2\pi U_2)\sim N(0,1)
$$
and f is
$$
f=\sqrt{-2\ln(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan\dfrac{W_1-W_2}{W_3-W_4}+\dfrac{1}{2})}\cdot \cos(2\arctan\dfrac{W_5-W_6}{W_7-W_8}+\pi)
$$

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Now I added specific proof. Just too excited :)

Answer (score 0):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
You're already part of the way there. Here's another way of reaching your goal that's somewhat less elegant than that given in [QiFeng233's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4884198/construction-of-standard-normal-distribution/4884210#4884210). As you say, your random variables $\ Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_5\ $ are independent, normally distributed random variables with zero mean.  It follows from this that the ratio $ \ \frac{\sqrt{5}\,\overline{Y}}{\overline{\sigma}_Y}\ $ of $\ \sqrt{5}\ $ times their sample mean
$$
\overline{Y}\ed\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^5Y_i
$$
to the square root $\ \overline{\sigma}_Y\ $ of their unbiased sample variance
$$
\overline{\sigma}_Y^2\ed\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^5\big(Y_i-\overline{Y}\big)^2
$$
follows a [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#How_the_t_distribution_arises_(characterization)) with $5$ degrees of freedom.  Let $\ g:(0,1)\rightarrow(-\infty,\infty)\ $ be the inverse of the standard normal cumulative distribution function—that is, the (unique) function such that
$$
g\big(\mathcal{N}(0,1,x)\big)=x
$$
for all $\ x\in(0,1)\ $—$\ \mathcal{T}_5\ $ the cumulative Student's t-distribution with $5$ degrees of freedom, and $\ f\ed g\circ \mathcal{T}_5\ .$ Then, because $\ f\ $ is strictly increasing,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(f\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\overline{Y}}{\overline{\sigma}_Y}\right)\le x\right)&=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\overline{Y}}{\overline{\sigma}_Y}\le f^{-1}(x)\right)\\
&=\mathcal{T}_5\big(f^{-1}(x)\big)\\
&=\mathcal{T}_5\big(\mathcal{T}_5^{-1}\big(g^{-1}(x)\big)\big)\\
&=\mathcal{N}(0,1,x)\ .
\end{align}
That is, $\ f\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}\,\overline{Y}}{\overline{\sigma}_Y}\right)\ $ follows a standard normal distribution.  Although there's no simple closed-form expression for the function $\ f\ ,$ it's nevertheless well-defined with no dependence on either of the parameters $\ \mu\ $ or $\ \sigma\ ,$ and could be easily evaluated using any of numerous calculators available for evaluating t-distributions and the inverse of the standard cumulative normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

$C=\frac{Z_1-Z_2}{Z_3-Z_4}$ is Cauchy standard and $\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan  C )$ is $N(0,1).$